# PDI connect to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: pentaho, mongodb-atlas, pentaho-data-integration

Using Pentaho Data Integration 9 community edition trying to connect to mongodb atlas but without success.
Tried the url mongodb provides:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@something.XYZ.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
org.pentaho.mongo.MongoDbException: Malformed host spec: mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@something.XYZ.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I saw a tips to change to old connection string, something similar to the following:

```
mongodb://user:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-wuhae.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-wuhae.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-wuhae.mongodb.net:27017/shop?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

but also without success.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to specify the replicaset instead since it doesnt seem to support the mongodb+srv syntax.
So in my case I had to add the following:

```
test-shard-00-01.XYZ.mongodb.net,test-shard-00-00.XYZ.mongodb.net,test-shard-00-02.XYZ.mongodb.net
```

Comment: how do you mean it? is this the whole line that you put in host-names?

Comment: yeah, just specify all the nodes as a string that is separated by a comma, then use the MongoDB Input step @StefanBuchholz